# create a basic manager class for typeorm library and vue.js project

Tags: typeorm

I would like to create a manager class typeorm for abstract and simplify code into vue.js side file.

I already created class and it seems to be work but not on the first launch app. 
Only after reload on the fly ! Perhaps the subject issue is async/await but I don't understand where is the place of error coding.

On the first launch my error is :

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: No metadata for "Public" was found

But if I add stupid code (for throw reload on the fly) I don't have again this error (perhaps the connection is established between the two loading code)

Can you help me to create (and understand) a basic class manager typeorm for creating lot of function (get, set, query, ...) which calling into my component vue.js ?

**This is my manager typeorm class (wrapper) :**

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm'
import {Public} from './../entity/Public'

export default class testConnectionManager
{
    init()
    {
        if (!typeorm.getConnectionManager().has("default"))
        {
            let connection = this.createConnection()
        }
        else
        {
            return typeorm.getConnectionManager().get("default")
        }
    }

    async createConnection()
    {
        let connection = await typeorm.getConnectionManager().create({
            type: "sqlite",
            database: './src/data/mydb.sql',
            entities: [
                Public,
            ],
        })

        let ok = await connection.connect()
    }

    testConnection()
    {
        let manager = typeorm.getConnectionManager()

        let test1 = manager.has("default")
        console.log(test1)
    }

    base2()
    {
        let connection = this.init()

        let toto = "toto"

        const defaultConnection = typeorm.getConnectionManager().get("default")

        let public1 = new Public()
        public1.name = "dirty public"

        defaultConnection.manager
            .save(public1)
            .then(public1 => {
                console.log("Public has been saved. Public id is", public1.id);
            })
    }

    base()
    {
        typeorm.createConnection({
            type: "sqlite",
            database: './src/data/mydb.sql',
            entities: [
                Public,
            ],
        }).then(connection => {

            let public1 = new Public()
            public1.name = "dirty public"

            return connection.manager
                .save(public1)
                .then(public1 => {
                    console.log("Public has been saved. Public id is", public1.id);
                });

        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    load()
    {
        typeorm.createConnection({
            type: "sqlite",
            database: './src/data/mydb.sql',
            entities: [
                Public,
            ],
        }).then(connection => {
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because TypeORM cannot resolve the path to the *Public* entity. In my case I set the entity path to my transpiled JavaScript files (I think I had the same problem in the beginning as you ), so you can try something like this:

```
typeorm.createConnection({
            type: "sqlite",
            database: './src/data/mydb.sql',
            entities: ['PATH_TO_ENTITY/**/*.js'],
        }).then(connection => { ...
```

Comment: Issue dealing with more promess than declaration of entities. I already other code that work with my declaration of entities into creation of connection.